# Calculating $\int_\Bbb{R}x^2e^{-x^2} dx$ using $\int_\Bbb{R}x^2e^{-tx^2} dx = -\frac{d}{dt}\int_\Bbb{R}e^{-tx^2} dx$

Tags: integration, exponential-function

How can I calculate
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} x^2e^{-x^2} dx
$$
with the help of this Identity
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} x^2e^{-tx^2} dx = -\frac{d}{dt}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-tx^2} dx
$$

Comment: Sufficient conditions are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: You should show some effort. But it helps to calculate the RHS first

Comment: You will need to use knowledge of the differentiated integral, yes. There are [any](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf) [number](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2827799) of proofs.

Comment: Do you know how to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} $?

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the function
$$
f(x,t)=e^{-t x^{2}}
$$
which is defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Obviously, $f$ is differentiable in $t$ :
$$
f^{\prime}(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x, t)=-x^2e^{-tx^2}
$$
The derivative $f^{\prime}(x, t)$ obviously has a majorant for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
$$
g(x)=0,
$$
which is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, since
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} 0 \hspace{1mm} d x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 0 \hspace{1mm} d x=0 .
$$
The function $x \mapsto f(x, t)$ is also integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ since for $t\geq 1$.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t x^{2}} d x\leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} d x=\sqrt{{\pi}}.
$$
Thus the function satisfies
$$
F(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-t x^{2}} d x
$$
all conditions and we obtain for all $t \geq 1$
$$
F^{\prime}(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} -x^2e^{-tx^2} d x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -x^2e^{-tx^2} d x.
$$
Thus the integral and the derivative are interchangeable and we obtain
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} x^2e^{-tx^2} dx =\int_\mathbb{R} -\frac{d}{dt} e^{-tx^2} dx=-\frac{d}{dt} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-tx^2} dx
$$
With the substitution
$$
u=\sqrt{t}x \rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}=\sqrt{t} \rightarrow dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}du
$$
we have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-u^2}du
$$
and we know that the gaussian integral is $\sqrt{\pi}$ so that
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} x^2e^{-tx^2} dx =-\frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \sqrt{\pi} = \dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}}{2\sqrt{t^3}}
$$
and for $t=1$ we finally get
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} x^2e^{-tx^2} dx= \dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}}{2}.
$$